# Regex to allow apostrophe only in words ending with 's

Tags: php, regex

I'm reading some files and I need to remove all the apostrophes in the strings except the ones in words ending with 's.

Examples:

> Frank's blue car -> Frank's blue car
>
> Frank 'blue' car -> Frank blue car
>
> 'Frank's blue car -> Frank's blue car
>
> Frank's' blue 'car -> Frank's blue car
>
> 'Frank blue car' -> Frank blue car
>
> Frank'blue'car -> Frankbluecar

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:** Modified question since I just need the words ending with 's to keep the apostrophe and not only the singular possessive ones.

Comment: Only `'` characters or also `’` characters?

Comment: can you precize your language (php, C#, java ...) please.

Comment: I specified the language (php) but @nick removed it from the tags.

Comment: @Stephan, why do we need language?  I removed the PHP tag because the question made no mention of it being important.  If you feel I made the wrong decision please, by all means, add the PHP tag.

Comment: @Nick the language indicates which flavour is in use, since regex varies from flavour to flavour. Some flavour may accept some extensions when others don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to disallow apostrophes that aren't surrounded by letters on both sides. You can try the following:

```
/(?<![a-z])'|'(?!s\b)/i
```

Replace anything that matches that with an empty string. If you want to allow some contractions also, you can broaden it a bit:

```
/(?<![a-z])'|'(?![a-z]\b)/i
```

This pattern matches your requirements, but I offer some notes of caution:

- It will block `'tis` and `'twas`, which are valid English.
- The first pattern will block most contractions, such as `didn't`.
- Without an English dictionary database, it will be impossible to distinguish between the singular-possessive (e.g. `Frank's`) and contractions ending in S (e.g. `she's`).
- Finally, remember that this will block most plural-possessives as well. This phrase is correct English, but it will still be blocked:

> the kids' toys

Comment: you are right about "he's","it,s" , however there are no verbs in the input

Comment: @Shaz - Added a `\b` to be a little more specific. Now it requires that the `'s` is the last thing in the word. Should work correctly for your `Frank's' blue 'car` example, yet strip out apostrophes in the middle of a word. For example, `foo'sbar's` becomes `foosbar's`.

Comment: It will match and remove apostrophe from `Jones' cat`, won't it?

Comment: @Staffan Nöteberg - That's actually not a singular possessive in English. If "Jones" is one person, you would write "Jones's cat".

Comment: E. Morgan I understand it as both ways are correct, but consistency is king. Also, many non-English words that end with a silent "s" or "x" will form their possessives with only an apostrophe, e.g. "Alexander Dumas' first novel." Actually, this ambiguous rule makes it impossible to do a regex to solve this. We need context that isn't available. Anyway, it's of course a corner case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :
`/(?<!s)'(?!s)\b/i`

Result :

```
Frank's blue car   ->  NO Match
Frank 'blue' car   ->  Match two single quotes
'Frank's blue car  ->  Match first single quote only
Frank's' blue 'car ->  Match all single quotes except the one in Franck
'Frank blue car'   ->  Match all single quotes
Frank'blue'car     ->  Match all single quotes
cars'              ->  NO Match
```

Comment: It will not match `'s` or `'sa`, will it?

Comment: This won't work. It won't match `Frank'blue car`, nor will it match `Franks' blue car`, `Frank'sblue car`, or anything other than an apostrophe right after a non-S character followed by a non-S word character. Actually, I'm not sure exactly how the `(?!s)` and `\b` are going to interact, only that it won't be the way you think. It may actually strip the apostrophe from `Frank's blue car`, but I'd have to test it. The `(?<!s)` is also wrong, since `Chris's car` should be just as valid as `Frank's car`.

Comment: @Staffan and @Justin, thanks for your comments. You both have pointed out some ambiguities. To solve this problem a sanitizing step on the input string should be performed for removing those ambiguities, before actually use the regex.

Comment: @Justion <pre>Frank'sblue car</pre> is an error. In this case, a second step could be performed to detect this problem.

Comment: This still needs some work. Your `\b` is redundant, since it's outside of the lookahead. The only effect it will have is that the pattern will fail to catch apostrophes at the end of a word (because `'\s` doesn't create a word boundary). Your test results aren't what I'm seeing: http://rextester.com/YKH54233

Answer (score 1):

How about using `(')([^sS][^ ]|$)`?  It should match all cases of apostrophes that you'd like to remove.  You should then use the contents of the second capture group to replace the entire matched content.

**Edit**: As discussed in the comments, this does not catch the case where the trailing s is dropped on words ending in an s, `cars' headlights` or `the Jones' cat`.

Comment: This would be erroneous for words ending with an s where the apostrophe is before a space rather than before an extra s.

Comment: @TVK, could you provide an example?  Having trouble understanding that description.

Comment: For example, you would say "Those cars' parts" rather than "Those cars's parts".

Comment: Very true.  I think that edge case eliminates the possibility of using an entirely regex solution.

Comment: Singular nouns always form the possessive by adding <’s> no matter their ending: <Bill’s, Felix’s, Janice’s, Taz’s, house’s, James’s, Ross’s, crisis’s, Illinois’s>. So do plural nouns <children’s, men’s, mice’s, criteria’s, stigmata’s> — *unless* that plural *already ends* in an <s> sound, making the possessive silent but marked with a simple <’>, which is of course **not** pronounced: <houses’, Kennedies’, crises’>. If you say an extra "uz" when spoken, then you must write <’s>, and if you don’t, you don’t. Hence <Achilles’ heel, for conscience’ sake>, which seem like exceptions but are not.

Comment: @tchrist - Out of curiosity, why aren't those exceptions? They seem to break the other rules.

Answer (score 1):

That command strips all surrounding single quotes except 
- possessives: mother's sister's ...
- short auxiliary verbs: don't isn't aren't ..

```
preg_replace("/(?<![a-z])'|'(?![st]\b)/i", '', $str)
```